# How to upgrade ASP.NET 5 from Beta6 to Beta7

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the cheatsheet for upgrading from Beta 6 to Beta 7 for ASP.NET 5 vNext?

Comment: This thread would be more appropriate on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/home)

Comment: Unfortunately I think there are too many breaking changes and even missing features for there to be a simple cheat sheet. The [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d) may help show you how you can translate some things.

Comment: @victor-hurdugaci github issues aren't collaboratively editable and the asp.net 5 wiki isn't not editable by non collaborators. DFowler has also commented that he doesn't want beta upgrade notes polluting the wiki. SO seems a good fit for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Prerequisites**

- Start from Beta 6 ([see prior notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745539/how-to-upgrade-asp-net-5-vnext-from-beta5-to-beta6))
- Install [Web Tools 2015 (Beta7)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738)
- Upgrade to beta7: `dnvm upgrade`
- Install x64 if you wish: `dnvm install 1.0.0-beta7 -arch x64 -r clr`
- Update the alias: `dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta7 x64`
- Set it as permanent default `dnvm use default -p`

**Beta 7 Changes**

Not all changes will be applicable to your project...

- Update `global.json` from `beta6` to `beta7`
- Search project.json files for `beta6"` and replace with `beta7"`
- In project.json, replace `Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions` with `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions`
- In project.json, replace `Kestrel` with `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`
- Replace `using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;` with `using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime;`
- Replace `configuration.GetConfigurationSection` with `configuration.GetSection`
- Replace `configuration.Get("MyConfigKey")` with `configuration["MyConfigKey"]`
- In Startup.cs, replace `services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>` with `services.AddMvc(options =>`

**Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity error**

My unit test projects had this error:

`Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: '<in-memory assembly>' and '<in-memory assembly>'`

[This blog](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/09/08/migration-notes-asp-net-5-mvc-6-beta-6-to-beta-7/) suggested moving `System.*` references down to framework specific section, I found removing them entirely also worked.

**TagBuilders**

One can no longer use `TagBuilder.ToString()` to get HTML but instead must make use of the `IHtmlContent` that it implements. See [TagBuilder InnerHtml in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416425/tagbuilder-innerhtml-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)

**Entity Framework**

- New syntax for migrations: `dnx ef migrations add MyMigration` and `dnx ef database update`

**Other**

- Further fixes may be found on the [ASP.NET announcements repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-beta7)
- Feel free to edit in your own findings

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one that ran into that weird "in-memory assembly" error! Drove me crazy for quite a while.

Comment: If you haven't already, rename `Kestrel` in `package.json` to `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`

Comment: "dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta7 x64" give me the following error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'x64'

Comment: closing and reopening the command prompt solved above problem.

Comment: Can I update it from my unit test project? My unit test uses .NET 4.5.2. I want to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the suggested "replace Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions with Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions"

Resolved me having the error "Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: '' and ''"

when I attempted to perform the upgrade.

Comment: That is an issue but caused by System.* references. The `Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions` doesn't exist in Beta7 so you can't not upgrade that